# kafka_Mongodb sync connector failing ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mongo-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted

Tags: aggregation-framework, apache-kafka-connect

Starting the sync jobs

```
bash-4.4# nohup ./bin/connect-standalone.sh ./config/connect-standalone-mongo.properties ./config/connect-mongo-sink.properties
```

## getting the following error..

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mongo-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:465)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Unknown schema type: null
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToConnect(JsonConverter.java:753)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:374)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:86)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
        ... 13 more
```

INFO StandaloneConfig values:

```
   access.control.allow.methods =
    access.control.allow.origin =
    admin.listeners = null
    bootstrap.servers = [172.18.0.7:9092]
    client.dns.lookup = default
    config.providers = []
    connector.client.config.override.policy = None
    header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
    internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

Sample config file as loaded...
INFO AdminClientConfig values:

```
bootstrap.servers = [172.18.0.7:9092]
client.dns.lookup = default
client.id =
connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 120000
retries = 5
```

[2020-04-11 11:51:49,331] INFO MongoSinkTopicConfig values:

```
   change.data.capture.handler =
    collection = changedata
    database = z**
    delete.on.null.values = false
    document.id.strategy = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.BsonOidStrategy
    field.renamer.mapping = []
    field.renamer.regexp = []
    key.projection.list =
    key.projection.type = none
    max.batch.size = 0
    max.num.retries = 3
    post.processor.chain = [com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder]
    rate.limiting.every.n = 0
    rate.limiting.timeout = 0
    retries.defer.timeout = 5000
    topic = changedata
```

What do I change or how to test the kafka_mongodb sink..?
I am also trying inside a container... to talk to outside Mongodb.
Kakfa and Zookeeper are running inside the container, I have got the necessary plugins and config file in correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct IP address of the Mongodb, and ports are opened, check the firewall and other security settings, also make sure you mongodb is listening on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1